# PHP - An error because of double quotes MYSQL query

Tags: php, sql, double, limit

```
 <?php
   $query = "SELECT * ";
   $query .= "FROM subjects ";
   $query .= "WHERE id='" . $subject_id ."' ";
   $query .= "LIMIT 1";
 ?>
```

The problem cause is in this line:
     
The error : "Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1"

So why... despite the syntax is right. Given me that error ?!

Comment: I have tested it myself with a testing table with the exact query above. It doesn't give me any errors. Perhaps this is not the query that gives you that error.

Comment: For debugging issues like this, a simple `echo $query;` immediately before preparing or executing the query can be an invaluable aid. What we need to see is the actual SQL text that is being passed to MySQL. The error is being thrown by a line of code not shown here.

Comment: @spencer7593: 1. without quotes 2. `var_dump`, not `echo`

Comment: Try `"SELECT * FROM \`subject\` WHERE \`id\` = '$subject_id' LIMIT 1"`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is from the execution of a line of code not shown in your question.

One obvious possibility is that the string value produced by this code is not being passed to MySQL. Another possibility is that `$subject_id` contains a string value that is being interpreted as SQL text, and the `$query` does not contain what you think it contains. There's a lot of other possibilities.

For debugging issues like this, we really need to identify the line of code that is actually throwing the error. (In your case, it's going to be a call to a mysql_, mysqli or PDO execute or prepare function or method.)

What you can do is add an `echo` or `var_dump` of the ACTUAL SQL text that is being passed to MySQL, on a line immediately preceding the line that is throwing the error.

For example, you would get this error message if a line of code after this code, and before the parse or execute call, modifies `$query`

```
$query .= " LIMIT 1";
```

That would add a second LIMIT clause on the query, which is invalid, and would throw the same error you are getting.

To reiterate: the lines of code posted in your question are NOT throwing an error. The lines of code you posted are simply assigning a string value to a variable. (This may be the string value that is being passed to MySQL, but we don't see that anywhere in your code.)

Comment: if it not passed it shouldn't work at all. but it work when it rounds by single quotes and by round i mean $subject_id
second $subject_id is an integer so it doesn't have to be in quotes. Right ?
this line i didn't understand "In your case, it's going to be a mysql_, mysqli or PDO execute or prepare."

Comment: @Kareem El-Hennawy: how the plastic are we supposed to know if the value contained in the `$subject_id` variable at the time your code runs is an integer? It could be null, it could be `'abc'`, it could be `0' OR '1'='1`, we have no freaking idea what `$subject_id` contains. And we have no clue whether `$query` is being modified later in the code, or even whether `$query` is being passed to MySQL. For all we know, you could have a later line of code that does: `$query .= " LIMIT 1";` before $query gets passed to MySQL.

Comment: @KareemEl-Hennawy, why aren't you still posting what is being requested?  Can we see the full code at least till the portion where you execute the query?

Comment: Okay. just explain to me you need the whole code ?
anyway here the main page which the error happens on : http://www.mediafire.com/?w05e1wjba66oqo1

Answer (score -1):

You are using `'subject_id'` may be int format have some problem so use `subject_id` and `Limit 1` alternate `Limit 0,1`.

```
<?php
   $query = "SELECT * ";
   $query .= "FROM subjects ";
   $query .= "WHERE id=" . $subject_id;
   $query .= "LIMIT 0,1";
 ?>
```

Comment: tried it and it doesn't work.. 
the error coming from the single quotes and it shouldn't be a problem ! and now the prevailing answer is that the value i am passing in is invalid

Comment: Please don't add links to your website to your answers.

Answer (score -4):

You don't need to concatenate the variable you can use

```
 <?php
 $query = "SELECT * ";
 $query .= "FROM subjects ";
 $query .= "WHERE id='$subject_id' ";
 $query .= "LIMIT 1";
  ?>
```

You have two semi-colons after your variable as well, and if your variable is a integer, it doesnt need to be in single quotes either.

Comment: And your code would produce **exactly the same** query. What problem your code doesn't have which OP's one has?

Comment: first what's OP ? second my question is about the single quotes you wrote around the $subject_id... why i have to write it like this..
the first form supposed to be right !

Comment: @Kareem El-Hennawy: OP is Original Poster, the question's author

Comment: @Kareem El-Hennawy: "supposed to be right" provide the plain text sql query without any php

Comment: you put single quotes around strings, but its not required for integers. If you use double quotes in the string, then you do not need to concatenate the variables.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM subject WHERE id = {$subject_id} LIMIT 1" and it also doesn't work.. all the formulations failed but the one with single quotes.. and i want to know why ?

Comment: Does this work, "SELECT * FROM subject WHERE id = $subject_id LIMIT 1"?
Is the variable an integer?

Comment: the variable is integer because it's id field in the database ! YES.
and this form doesn't work "SELECT * FROM subject WHERE id = $subject_id LIMIT 1"

Comment: echo out the code, and then copy into phpmyadmin and run the sql, see if it works in there.